ValidationError: 1 validation error for SubQuestionList using Llama index example for Lyft and Uber
I am trying this example https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y_lUUKMdC627J5EP0dK1H8NveovpYisM?usp=sharing#scrollTo=nnxo0qEewD91 from Llama index documentation. I try it in a Colab environment. Everything works until i try to ask a question which needs to be split in sub questions.

!pip install llama-index llama-hub pypdf langchain-openai llama-index-embeddings-azure-openai llama-index-llms-azure-openai
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, ServiceContext, VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.core.tools import QueryEngineTool, ToolMetadata
from llama_index.core.query_engine import SubQuestionQueryEngine
import nest_asyncio
from llama_index.llms.azure_openai import AzureOpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.azure_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbedding

nest_asyncio.apply()
from IPython.display import HTML, display

def set_css():
  display(HTML('''
  <style>
    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
  </style>
  '''))
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', set_css)
api_key = "6...."
azure_endpoint = "https://..."
api_version = "2024-02-15-preview"

llm = AzureOpenAI(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    deployment_name="gpt-35-turbo",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
)

# You need to deploy your own embedding model as well as your own chat completion model
embed_model = AzureOpenAIEmbedding(
    model="text-embedding-ada-002",
    deployment_name="text-embedding-ada-002",
    api_key=api_key,
    azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
    api_version=api_version,
)
from llama_index.core import Settings

Settings.llm = llm
Settings.embed_model = embed_model
!wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/qctkz6nxhm0y5qe/lyft_2021.pdf?dl=1 -O lyft_2021.pdf
!wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/te0a2w227v27iag/uber_2021.pdf?dl=1 -O uber_2021.pdf
lyft_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["lyft_2021.pdf"]).load_data()
uber_docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=["uber_2021.pdf"]).load_data()
# setup baseline index
base_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(lyft_docs + uber_docs)
base_engine = base_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=4)
response = base_engine.query("What are some risk factors for Uber?")
print(str(response))

Uber faces various risk factors that could harm its business, financial condition, and operating results. These include, but are not limited to, the potential harm to its reputation and ability to attract and retain drivers, consumers, merchants, shippers, and carriers due to criminal, violent, inappropriate, or dangerous activity by platform users and third parties. Uber's ability to protect or provide a safe environment for its users may be compromised due to certain actions by drivers, consumers, merchants, carriers, and third parties. The accuracy of background checks on potential or current drivers is limited in certain jurisdictions according to national and local laws, and third-party service providers may fail to conduct such background checks adequately or disclose relevant information. Uber may also face litigation related to claims by drivers for the actions of consumers or third parties, and operating a motor vehicle is inherently dangerous. The growth of Uber's delivery offering has led to an increase in couriers on two-wheel vehicles such as scooters and bicycles, who are more vulnerable road users and face a more severe level of injury in the event of a collision than that faced while driving in a vehicle. Uber's auto liability and general liability insurance policies may not cover all potential claims to which it is exposed, and may not be adequate to indemnify it for all liability. Uber also faces risks related to data security breaches, the development of new offerings and technologies, and the successful introduction of new or upgraded products, offerings, or features for its users.
response = base_engine.query("Compare and contrast the risk factors of Uber and Lyft?")
print(str(response))

I'm sorry, but the given context information does not provide any comparison between the risk factors of Uber and Lyft. The context information only provides information about the risk factors and challenges faced by Lyft, including competition, operational factors, seasonality, brand and marketing, commitment to safety, and government regulation. There is no information provided about the risk factors of Uber or any comparison between the two companies.
lyft_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(lyft_docs)
uber_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(uber_docs)
lyft_engine = lyft_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=2)
uber_engine = uber_index.as_query_engine(similarity_top_k=2)
query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=lyft_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="lyft_10k",
            description="Provides information about Lyft financials for year 2021",
        ),
    ),
    QueryEngineTool(
        query_engine=uber_engine,
        metadata=ToolMetadata(
            name="uber_10k",
            description="Provides information about Uber financials for year 2021",
        ),
    ),
]
from llama_index.core.query_engine import SubQuestionQueryEngine
s_engine = SubQuestionQueryEngine.from_defaults(query_engine_tools=query_engine_tools,use_async=True)
response = s_engine.query("Compare the risk factors of Uber and Lyft?")
print(str(response))


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py in parse_raw(cls, b, content_type, encoding, proto, allow_pickle)
    538         try:
--> 539             obj = load_str_bytes(
    540                 b,

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/v1/parse.py in load_str_bytes(b, content_type, encoding, proto, allow_pickle, json_loads)
     36             b = b.decode(encoding)
---> 37         return json_loads(b)
     38     elif proto == Protocol.pickle:

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()

/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f1ff9b6d64d7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 response = s_engine.query("Compare the risk factors of Uber and Lyft?")
      2 print(str(response))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/core/instrumentation/dispatcher.py in wrapper(func, instance, args, kwargs)
    209             self.span_enter(id_=id_, bound_args=bound_args, instance=instance)
    210             try:
--> 211                 result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    212             except BaseException as e:
    213                 self.event(SpanDropEvent(span_id=id_, err_str=str(e)))

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/core/base/base_query_engine.py in query(self, str_or_query_bundle)
     51             if isinstance(str_or_query_bundle, str):
     52                 str_or_query_bundle = QueryBundle(str_or_query_bundle)
---> 53             query_result = self._query(str_or_query_bundle)
     54         dispatch_event(QueryEndEvent())
     55         return query_result

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/core/query_engine/sub_question_query_engine.py in _query(self, query_bundle)
    143             CBEventType.QUERY, payload={EventPayload.QUERY_STR: query_bundle.query_str}
    144         ) as query_event:
--> 145             sub_questions = self._question_gen.generate(self._metadatas, query_bundle)
    146 
    147             colors = get_color_mapping([str(i) for i in range(len(sub_questions))])

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/question_gen/openai/base.py in generate(self, tools, query)
     86         query_str = query.query_str
     87         question_list = cast(
---> 88             SubQuestionList, self._program(query_str=query_str, tools_str=tools_str)
     89         )
     90         return question_list.items

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/program/openai/base.py in __call__(self, llm_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    184 
    185         tool_calls = message.additional_kwargs["tool_calls"]
--> 186         return _parse_tool_calls(
    187             tool_calls,
    188             output_cls=self.output_cls,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_index/program/openai/base.py in _parse_tool_calls(tool_calls, output_cls, allow_multiple, verbose)
     62             output = output_cls.parse_obj(function_call.arguments)
     63         else:
---> 64             output = output_cls.parse_raw(function_call.arguments)
     65 
     66         outputs.append(output)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py in parse_raw(cls, b, content_type, encoding, proto, allow_pickle)
    546             )
    547         except (ValueError, TypeError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
--> 548             raise ValidationError([ErrorWrapper(e, loc=ROOT_KEY)], cls)
    549         return cls.parse_obj(obj)
    550 

ValidationError: 1 validation error for SubQuestionList
__root__
  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (type=value_error.jsondecode; msg=Expecting value; doc=const SubQuestionList: functions.SubQuestionList = ({ items }) => {
  return {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      "Uber Risk Factors": {
        type: "array",
        items: [
          {
            type: "string",
            description: "What are the risk factors for Uber?",
            tool_name: "uber_10k",
          },
        ],
      },
      "Lyft Risk Factors": {
        type: "array",
        items: [
          {
            type: "string",
            description: "What are the risk factors for Lyft?",
            tool_name: "lyft_10k",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  };
};
SubQuestionList({ items: [] });
; pos=0; lineno=1; colno=1)

